# Two-way string matching with wildcard characters on both sides in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a situation where I have a list of 8 character-long strings containing wildcard characters (represented by `?`), that I need to match to an input string that also has wildcard characters. Said string is composed of four alphabetic characters (A-Z) followed by four numbers (0-9). To make it easier to understand, here's an example of a set of strings:

```
ABCD1234
A??D123?
A???????
?BC1234?
```

If I give `A?CD12?4` as input, the comparison should resolve to true in every comparison.

My current implementation is using Hashmap, using the string as key and the same string parsed as regex as the object mapped. For instance `A?CD12?4` becomes `A([A-Z]|\\?)CD12([0-9]|\\?)4`, and then using the following code to obtain a set of the compatible strings:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("A???????", "A([A-Z]|\\?)([A-Z]|\\?)([A-Z]|\\?)([0-9]|\\?)([0-9]|\\?)([0-9]|\\?)([0-9]|\\?)");
map.put("ABCD1234", "ABCD1234");
map.put("A??D123?", "A([A-Z]|\\?)([A-Z]|\\?)D123([0-9]|\\?)");
map.put("?BCD123?", "([A-Z]|\\?)BC123([0-9]|\\?)");


String str = "A?CD12?4";
String strReg = "A([A-Z]|\\?)CD12([0-9]|\\?)4";

Set<Object> set = map.keySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(s -> str.matches(map.get(s)) || s.matches(strReg) )
               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

However, this still missed inputs where a wildcard question mark in `str` but not on the map string (for instance, the input `A?CD1234` would not resolve as true for `?BCD1234` and vice-versa).

While I know this would be trivial to fix by iterating over the String, my solution requires the input to be compared to over **50000** Strings, and I read inputs at a rate of around **30/second**, so performance is key.

This processing happens inside a Thread, and outside interaction can change the list of strings the input will check (add or remove only).

Comment: Not an answer but if you wish to improve the performance of your code you should compile the regexes to Pattern's and store those in the map rather than Strings - same for strReg and then adjust the filter to match.

Comment: The list of strings could change during execution - I shall add this constraint to the original question.

Comment: If it **could** change then my point still stands. It is a simple optimisation that will be worth it if the same regular expression is being matched more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, your `?` wildcard can be ignored when comparing strings. Since this can be used for all of the patterns, there is no need to store the regex alternative in a map, it can be inferred when iterating that the character can be skipped. Here's a faster solution using parallel streams:

```
Set<String> patterns = new HashSet<>();

patterns.add("A???????");
patterns.add("ABCD1234");
patterns.add("A??D123?");
patterns.add("?BCD123?");

String s = "A?CD12?4";

Set<String> matches = patterns.parallelStream() // the main benefit of this
                              .filter(p -> {
                                  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                                      char a = s.charAt(i),
                                           b = p.charAt(i);
                                      if (a != '?' && b != '?' && a != b)
                                          return false;
                                  }
                                  return true;
                              }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: This only considers the wildcard being on the side of the list strings, but not on input. If the input is A?CD1234, it will fail for ?BCD1234 for instance, because ? doesn't match B.

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer so that it super-imposes all wildcards in the input into each pattern before testing if it matches.

Comment: If you get the chance, I'm curious as to what the performance is like of the current solutions here. I'm not able to test because I don't have 50,000 strings. I can just speculate.

Comment: you just blew my mind for showing that you can make a multi-line predicate on filter. If Andy's solution doesn't work for my project, I shall test yours.

Comment: I removed the regex from my answer, because I started to notice several inefficiencies that popped up, and it was more work than it was worth. This answer is now a combination of the other great answer with parallel streams.

Comment: While I made the comparison in a separate function, this is the closest to the solution I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use regex for this. Just compare the characters of the two strings directly:

```
boolean formatCorrect(String a) {
 if (a.length() != 8) return false;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    char ca = a.charAt(i);
    if (ca != '?' && !Character.isLetter(ca)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 4; i < 8; ++i) {
    char ca = a.charAt(i);
    if (ca != '?' && !Character.isDigit(ca)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

boolean stringsMatch(String a, String b) {
  if (!formatCorrect(a) || !formatCorrect(b)) {
    // Handle this. Maybe an IllegalArgumentException?
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    char ca = a.charAt(i);
    char cb = b.charAt(i);
    if (ca != '?' && cb != '?' && ca != cb) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This would be very fast because it isn't allocating any objects.

You could optimise it by moving some of the checks out of the loops (e.g. the checks that strings `a` and `b` are of the correct format in and of themselves).

Comment: This solution proved to be extremely fast indeed (tested with a list of 120000 strings with 100 sequential inputs). I will try to implement this into our solution and I'll be back to report results with real data.